# Word Anagram not getting all user input

Tags: java, arrays, user-input

I am writing a program checking if n words are anagrams of the initially given word. It the word is an anagram it prints "yes", if it isn't - prints "no". It solves the problem correctly if I input all the data manually in the console. If I copy and paste the data it does not "see" the last line until I hit enter again. So it I paste the following input:

```
anagram
6
gramana
aaagrnm
anagra
margana
abc
xy
```

So I get only 5 yes-es and no-s and when I hit enter again I get the last no.

here is my code

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class WordAnagrams {

    public static void anagramCheck (String x, String y) {
        char[] initial= new char[x.length()];
        for (int i=0; i<x.length(); i++) {
            initial[i]=x.charAt(i);
        }
        Arrays.sort(initial);

        char[] isAnagram = new char[y.length()];
        for (int i=0; i<y.length(); i++) {
            isAnagram[i]=y.charAt(i);
            // System.out.println(isAnagram[i]);
        }
        Arrays.sort(isAnagram); 
        boolean same=Arrays.equals(initial, isAnagram);

        if (same) {
        System.out.println ("yes");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println ("no");
        }
        // return answer;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String word = input.nextLine();
        int n = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
        String anagram=""; // input.nextLine();
        // int counter=0;

        System.out.println();

        /* while (counter<n+1) {
            anagram=input.nextLine();
            anagramCheck(word, anagram);
            // anagram=input.nextLine();
            counter++;
        }*/

        for (int i=0; i<=n; i++) {
            anagram=input.nextLine();
            anagramCheck(word, anagram);
            // anagram=input.nextLine();
        // System.out.println(answers[i]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

Comment: next line will only feed to the program only if a new line character is entered, that is why the last output is only getting printed after you press enter,  you can try to copy with a new line

Comment: I got this question from an online practice site and the judge system there does not accept my solution and I don't have control on how it feeds the data.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that when you copy paste the input, the last word have no '\n' at the end so the scanner doesn't read this as a line until you press ENTER.

So what I can propose is:

1) Use a File for an Input
Or 2) Use InputStreamReader to fetch from the console. Here is some code to do it:

```
`
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        char buffer[] = new char[512];
        InputStreamReader input = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        input.read(buffer,0,512);
        String data[] = (new String(buffer)).split("\n");
    }
`
```

It give you a list of strings at the end. PS: Your loop "for(int i =0;i<=n;i++)" is looping 7 times with n = 6.

Answer (score 0):

@kalina199
You could also shorten your code a bit to save yourself from defining a method to check the input from the console.
I did it by splitting the console input into a String array using a simple regex and immediately sorted it.
Then my loop does a simple check to compare the new user input to the original word by their lengths and if that doesn't match you just print out "no" and continue with the next word.
Here's my code:

```
package bg.Cholakov;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Anagram {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[] initWord = scanner.nextLine().split("");
        Arrays.sort(initWord);
        int num = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());

        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            String[] testWord = scanner.nextLine().split("");
            Arrays.sort(testWord);
            if (!(initWord.length == testWord.length)) {
                System.out.println("no");
            } else if (initWord[i].equals(testWord[i])) {
                System.out.println("yes");
            } else {
                System.out.println("no");
            }
        }
    }
}
```